# getting value inside double quotes , preceded by a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm thinking to do two regex for get $price and then 33fff50.00 in this string:

```
Variable "$price" got invalid value "33fff50.00"
```

both regex are preceded for 'Variable' and 'value' word:

I've tried:

```
\b[Variable ]"(.*)"
```

but it's not working

Comment: _both regex are preceded for 'Variable' and 'value' word:_ And both are wrapped in double quotes. Can you just extract values in double quotes?

Comment: not really, need to find the word inside quotes preceding the key, because  the string can have a lot of double quotes after, it's a long string

Comment: You might want to look up what square brackets mean in a regex

Comment: `\bVariable "(.*?)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `variable` and `value` are fixed strings with special meaning, then try

```
var matches = str.match( /variable\s+\"(.*)".*value\s+\"(.*)\"/i )
if (matches)
{
   console.log( "variable ", matches[1] );
   console.log( "value ", matches[2] );
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = 'Variable "$price" got invalid value "33fff50.00"';
var matches = str.match( /variable\s+\"(.*)".*value\s+\"(.*)\"/i )
if (matches)
{
   console.log( "variable ", matches[1] );
   console.log( "value ", matches[2] );
}
```

Comment: very nice, it's working, just I delete '$' with .replace() , maybe is a way to delete '$' with regex?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be

```
\bVariable[^"]+"([^"]+)"[^"]+"([^"]+)"
```

Broken down this says:

```
\b        # word boundary
Variable  # Variable literally
[^"]+     # not a double quote, 1+ times
"([^"]+)" # capture anything between double quotes into group 1
[^"]+     # same as above
"([^"]+)" # group 2
```

Here, you need to take group 1 and 2, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/eia30o/1).

---

Additionally, `\b[Variable ]` does not do what you think it does. It'll look for *one* of `V`, `a`, `r`, `i`, `a`, `b`, `l`, `e`.